# using JMeter to test an ASP application

Tags: asp-classic, jmeter

I am using `JMeter` to test an `ASP` application.
I can correctly log in with a name and password, but when I send a request to the next page, I get a response that I am not logged in correctly.
It seems the application does not understand that I am the same person that just logged in.
The application does not seem to use variables like `EVENTSTATE`. It also does not use cookies to save session information.

Doe anybody know what I’m doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there (welcome to SO!), could you describe in a little more detail how you are trying to use Jmeter? It sounds like you have used the jmeter proxy server to record a test on your ASP application, and when you replay it, it isn't logging in?

Answer (score 0):

add a Cookie Manager to your test Plan.
See :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Cookie_Manager